# What tool should i use to manage cybercafe on preferably latest Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, cybercafe

Im from Ukraine, and i have 12 windows-xp licensed computers.
Could you suggest some neat client-server app? Lesser it costs is better:)

Maybe there're some SteamOS plugin/adoon?

Comment: Ubuntu is free all the way. You can replace everything with Ubuntu if you want. What you shouldn't be using is XP, no longer supported, no security updates since 2014 (?), basically a sitting duck waiting to be shot at with anything. A standalone XP running some old software to control let's say an industrial machine isn't a problem. Networked and with internet access plus cybercafe users... Are you out of your mind?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Mkahawa - An OpenSource Cyber Manager.

Link:  http://mkahawa.sourceforge.net/